# find a daily weight problem from moving sum in sliding window

Tags: number-theory

There is spot where can be placed $p$ grams of feeds. ($p \in N, 0$)

Every morning, The farmer put $p_d$ grams of feeds. ($d$ is days, $d \in N$) but $k$ days after, then farmer also get $p_{d-k}$ grams at same times.

If we only knows about sum of $p_{d-k+1}, p_{d-k+2}..., p_d$ $(d \ge n)$, then we can find out $p_d$?

For example, If there are 2 spots, then I can find out any $p$ in two cases.

1. $p_{k} + p_{k+1} = 0$
2. $p_{k} + p_{k+1} = 1$, $p_{k+1} + p_{k+2} = 2$, $p_{k+2} + p_{k+3} = 1$

But these are useless in the real world because the farmer doesn't forget to feed and the weight is always not small. (like 130g, 532g, 421g...)

Here are my questions...

1. There are any other cases to find out any $p$ grams?
2. Or any equations for solution?
3. If both are not exist, why?

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, if the sum of $k$ days feeding windows $P_d$ is know, then the daily feeding $p_d$ is known:
$$
P_d=\sum_{i=d-k+1}^{d} p_i\\
p_d=P_d-P_{d-1}+p_{d-k}\\
...\\
p_k=P_d-P_{k-1}+p_0\\
$$
As you can realize, for knowing the daily feeding $p_d$, you must know both the initial daily feeding $p_0$ and the initial feeding window $P_{k-1}$ for the first $k-1$ days.

This is a recurrence equation in discrete time, or equivalently, an autoregressive model (a boring one) if taking $p_d$ as input and $P_d$ as output.